# Multiple instances of same file import causes file NOT to be imported at all

Tags: less

I have a conditional statement which imports a file based on which type of menu has been set.

In this example, "nav-main-type" has been set to "dual," so the second "__type" should run and import "menu-main-mobile.less" inside a "not desktop" media query.

It does seem to import fine, but the file doesn't compile to CSS. When I comment out the import from the first "__type", everything works fine, so the problem seems to be having two imports of the same file...

It shouldn't be a problem because only one "__type" can ever run, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

```
.Menu-Main();
@Menu-Main: on;

.Menu-Main (@Menu-Main: on) when (@Menu-Main = on) {
  @import 'menu-main.less';
  @type: @nav-main-type;
  .__type () when (@type = mobile) {
    @import 'parts/menu-main-mobile.less';
  }
  .__type () when (@type = dual)   {
    @media @q-dt   {@import 'menu-main-desktop.less';}
    @media @q-ntdt {@import 'parts/menu-main-mobile.less';}
  }
  .__type();
}
```

Comment: You need to use [`@import (multiple)`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options). Note that imports are performed right where/when they appear n the code and *not* when you call the mixin (i.e. in your above example it's always double import of "menu-main-mobile" regardless of any conditions). Mixins (and its conditions) only control where you expand a content of these *already imported* imports.